# PHP Cookies not setting

Tags: php, cookies

I have a script so when a user enters an incorrect CAPTCHA on the contact me form I have it saves the users form data to a cookie so it can be recalled when the user has to re-enter the CAPTCHA. But it's not saving the cookie, I've checked the Chrome Debugger, and it's not doing anything.

Here's the code, I've checked that the variables are successfully working before anyone asks ;)

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
setcookie("name", $name, time()+3600, "/", "http://pattersoncode.ca");
setcookie("email", $email, time()+3600, "/", "http://pattersoncode.ca");
setcookie("message", $message, time()+3600, "/", "http://pattersoncode.ca");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `http://` in your domain parameter; it specifies a protocol, namely, HTTP, and is not part of the domain.

If you want set a cookie effective for `example.com`, `subdomain.example.com` will only work on that subdomain, while setting `.example.com` will work on all subdomains (including the root domain).

In short, try with these:

```
setcookie("name", $name, time()+3600, "/", ".pattersoncode.ca");
setcookie("email", $email, time()+3600, "/", ".pattersoncode.ca");
setcookie("message", $message, time()+3600, "/", ".pattersoncode.ca");
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that you **must** call `setcookie()` **before** printing out any content, either with a printing function like `echo` and `printf`, or outside the `<?php ?>` tags (that still counts as printing). Did you check for that?

Comment: Uhh, yep.. There is 1 include before the cookies are set, but it is required to check if the captcha is correct or not so if I remove that it defeats the purpose.